# Ideas to hide pipe between bathtub and drain

Tags: bathroom, drain

not sure if it's the right forum for my question, but I'll give it a shot. I'm about to start a quick and cheap renovation of my Bathroom (basically putting some finish on top of the walls and floor without knocking down the existing tiles first).

I have this bathtub shown in the picture in my Bathroom, and someone decided that the Drain should be in the middle of the Room, with a pipe leading from the bathtub over the floor and down the drain.

[image]

If I were to redo the flooring, I'd raise it, move the drain and change the bathtub for a shower, but it's not an option.

My question is if anyone has any idea on how to hide this ugly drain pipe (and perhaps the metal vents as well) without moving the bathtub, moving the drain or raising the floor.

All ideas are welcome, though some of them may not be accomplishable due to details I have forgot here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes a step is put along the side of a tub to assist in entry. You could form one that straddles and covers the pipe and half the floor drain. Just make it removable (screws are OK if accessible) so that you can access the drain if needed.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. And probably the solution i'd go with if I didn't have the bathroom door to the right in the picture, and the drain pipe is so long that the step would extend into the doorframe. I could of course make a shorter step, but that wouldn't look as natural.

Comment: Steps can also have a curves front profile, or angled corners to increase the room between the door and step.